# R rpart creating terminal nodes table

Tags: r, decision-tree

I would like to create a table from my rpart output (see below).

The table basically should contain the following variables as data frame:
- terminal nodes number (for the example below 4,10,22,23,3)
- terminal nodes observation
- terminal nodes target cnt (number of absent or present in each node)

However I would like to do it automatically as I change or prune tree.

Any suggestion?

```
library(rpart)
rp <- rpart(Kyphosis ~ Age + Number + Start, data = kyphosis)
rp
```

Comment: `rp$frame` has all the info you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`rp$frame$var` tells you whether or not a node is a leaf. It is slightly obscure that the node number is the row name in rp$frame. So what you want is

```
rownames(rp$frame)[rp$frame$var == "<leaf>"]
[1] "4"  "10" "22" "23" "3"
```

If you want *numbers* instead of strings that look like numbers, you could use

```
as.numeric(rownames(rp$frame)[rp$frame$var == "<leaf>"])
[1]  4 10 22 23  3
```